# Expo React Native stuck on splash screen when redux and redux-thunk is imported

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I have no idea what is the reason why the app is stuck on the splash screen.
I have tried debugging the app and this only happens when redux and redux-thunk is imported.

These are the errors that are showing up:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNShare.FACEBOOK')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
```

&

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

Comment: Tried deleting node_modules and rerunning `npm i`, then restarting the application?

Comment: @SnazzyMohit yes already tried that as well still stuck on splash screen with that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I was using `./gradlew assembleRelease` to generate an APK, but using `./gradlew assembleDebug` fixed this issue for me. All I need was to generate an APK and this command got it going for me, I don't know why.